# Unsuccessful place order stock levels decrease

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, stock, inventory

I have been creating an observer that fires after an order gets placed. When creating the code I accidentally added the wrong syntax for Mage::log, so when I pressed the "Place order" button, Magento tried to create the order (gif rotates "place order" button disappears)but then stops. I have noticed that If I keep pressing the place order button the stock levels for the products in the order decreases, but obviously no order is created. If I then fix my observer and refresh the order page then select place order, my order number is not sequential from the other orders. So does this mean that Magento will assign the stock to be deducted to the order first, then if the order doesn't get processed the order gets deleted so there is no way to return the stock levels to Magento as there is no longer an order. If this is the case is there any way round this process in case any issue arises that could prevent the order from being generated?